# How to compile Item Template Project for Form with substitute parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, msbuild, vsix, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to make an ItemTemplate for a Form. I create a "c# Item Tamplate"-Project, make my Form, and create my Template by Building the project. That works fine.

Now I want to add [Templateparameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/eehb4faa.aspx) but as soon as I do, the project wont compile any more. It throws many different exceptions because the code is no longer valid. How can I solve this problem?

Here is what I tried so far:

- Replacing every occurrence of my Classname with $safeitemname$. This, as I already said, throws exception because now the code is invalid and the project can not be built.
- Creating CustomParameters in my .vstemplate to change a valid class name to my desired parameter (Classname -> $safeitemname$). This does nothing, even though I set "Replaceparameters="True"".
- Ignoring the compiler warnings and implementing the project in my .vsix project anyway. This does nothing either, because the .zip for my template still can not be.
- Setting DependentUpon of my Classname.Designer.cs to my Classname.cs. This does nothing either.
- Trying a simple ItemTemplate with one class that's divided in two partial classes that have one Property each. Same thing as  with the Form. It can no longer be build.

Comment: Build action of templates should be `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Reza Aghaei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3110834/reza-aghaei) suggested in his comment, the problem was, that I didn't set the build action for the files in my project to 'None'.

Comment: Thanks!! been fighting with this for a while when adding multiple source files to the same Item Template project.